# Oracle SQL - Select large number as hex string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where one of its column is a number.
How can I select this column as an hexadecimal string?

I tried to use `to_char(my_column, 'xxxx')` but that's not what I want since the column I want to select doesn't always have the same value and the second parameter of `to_char` needs to be the exact same size as the output hex string. To be honest, I feel like this is stupid cause you need to know the returned value of `to_char` before calling `to_char` to be able to construct it's second parameter.

Comment: how can you express something if you don't know what it is ;)

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu Exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `fm` format model with `TO_CHAR` which will strip the leading whitespace and then just include enough `X` characters to display the largest value you need to accommodate:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(
         value,
         'fmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
       ) AS hex_value
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY value;
```

Which for the test data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
SELECT POWER( 2, 4 * (LEVEL-1) ) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20 UNION ALL
SELECT POWER( 2, 4 * (LEVEL-1) ) - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>                   VALUE | HEX_VALUE           
> ----------------------: | :-------------------
>                       0 | 0                   
>                       1 | 1                   
>                      15 | F                   
>                      16 | 10                  
>                     255 | FF                  
>                     256 | 100                 
>                    4095 | FFF                 
>                    4096 | 1000                
>                   65535 | FFFF                
>                   65536 | 10000               
>                 1048575 | FFFFF               
>                 1048576 | 100000              
>                16777215 | FFFFFF              
>                16777216 | 1000000             
>               268435455 | FFFFFFF             
>               268435456 | 10000000            
>              4294967295 | FFFFFFFF            
>              4294967296 | 100000000           
>             68719476735 | FFFFFFFFF           
>             68719476736 | 1000000000          
>           1099511627775 | FFFFFFFFFF          
>           1099511627776 | 10000000000         
>          17592186044415 | FFFFFFFFFFF         
>          17592186044416 | 100000000000        
>         281474976710655 | FFFFFFFFFFFF        
>         281474976710656 | 1000000000000       
>        4503599627370495 | FFFFFFFFFFFFF       
>        4503599627370496 | 10000000000000      
>       72057594037927935 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFF      
>       72057594037927936 | 100000000000000     
>     1152921504606846975 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF     
>     1152921504606846976 | 1000000000000000    
>    18446744073709551615 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF    
>    18446744073709551616 | 10000000000000000   
>   295147905179352825855 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF   
>   295147905179352825856 | 100000000000000000  
>  4722366482869645213695 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  
>  4722366482869645213696 | 1000000000000000000 
> 75557863725914323419135 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 
> 75557863725914323419136 | 10000000000000000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=48e9bbe37d6bfa1fe47c91afd4b2b02d)*

Answer (score 0):

The format mask does not always have to be the same size as the number of characters that the hex value is. You can use a large format mask (lots of x's) then use `LTRIM` to remove the extra spaces.

```
WITH
    strings (string_val)
    AS
        (SELECT '28' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '589' FROM DUAL)
SELECT string_val, LTRIM (TO_CHAR (string_val, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')) as hex_value
  FROM strings;



   STRING_VAL    HEX_VALUE
_____________ ____________
28            1C
589           24D
```